How do these two notions of "multiplicative approximation" relate?
While reading a few quantum supremacy results, I have come across two ostensibly different notions of "multiplicative approximation". I am wondering how they relate. In the following, $p$ and $q$ are discrete probability distributions that are supported on the same set $X$.
On one hand, there is the definition used in, for example, the IQP paper by Bremner, Jozsa, and Shepherd. There, they say (or rather this is equivalent to what they say) that $p$ approximates $q$ to within $\epsilon \geq 0$ in multiplicative error if for all $x \in X$, $$\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}q(x) \leq p(x) \leq (1 + \epsilon)q(x).$$
On the other hand, there is the definition used in, for example, a different IQP paper by Bremner, Montanaro, Shepherd. There, they say that $p$ approximates $q$ to within $\epsilon \geq 0$ in multiplicative error if for all $x \in X$, $$|p(x) - q(x)| \leq \epsilon q(x).$$
My question is if these are equivalent definitions, or if at least one implies the other.
It seems the latter definition almost implies the former. I say "almost" because if $p(x) \geq q(x)$ for all $x \in X$, then indeed one can easily recover the former definition. However, if there are $x$ for which $p(x) < q(x)$, then I don't see how to recover it.
Are these definitions equivalent? If they are not, does the latter definition imply the former?

They are equivalent, but not with the same epsilon.

Sure, the best I can do is see that if for all $x$, $|p(x) - q(x)| \leq \epsilon q(x)$, then $(1 - \epsilon)q(x) \leq p(x) \leq (1 - \epsilon)^{-1} q(x)$, which is multiplicative by the former definition with $\epsilon' = (1 - \epsilon)^{-1} - 1$. Is this the best one can do?

Try to find tight examples!

... I mean, it is really just a function of a single number (divide by q, then only p/q remains), so checking tightness is really just plotting the curve.
